# installing toolbox in matlab from one computer to another

Tags: installation, matlab

I'm on a computer with multiple versions of matlab installed, not all versions share the same toolboxes. For some reason, I was able to "install" a new toolbox to one matlab version by copying the toolbox folder from one to another and setting its folder path in matlab.

My question is, why does this work? If I were to copy my toolbox from another computer to this computer, would I expect the same result?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but if you want to use the alternate toolbox on the same computer I think this is how it can be done:

1. Remove the undesired toolbox from the `path`
2. Add the new location of the toolbox

This should work better than (or the same as) copying the entire folder.